# Unshelve to another branch

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfs-power-tools

I'm trying to unpack my changes to the another branch using TFS Power Tools. I'm trying to execute command

```
tfpt unshelve /migrate "NuGet Build" "/source:$/ProjectName/Main/Source" "/target:$/ProjectName/Main/Source-NuGet"
```

But it returns message `'tfpt : Unable to determine the workspace'`.

I'm running command from the directory that mapped to this project. Moreover I've tried to 
use `tf workspaces /s:http://our-tfs`.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: looking at your path names, it doesn't look like you're moving between branches (both the source and the target are in the Main branch)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out where the problem.
I'm tried to use TFS Power Tools 2008 because we are using TFS 2008. But I should use TFS Power Tools the same version as the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 37):

You can define your path in cmd with the TFPT. And then, from there, you go to the destination folder or workspace where you want to unshelve your code.

```
1. c:\>path = %path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools

2. cd c:\[some location]\"destination workspace"

3. tfpt unshelve /migrate "NuGet Build" /source:"$/ProjectName/Main/Source" /target:"$/ProjectName/Main/Target-NuGet"
```

Here you have a video that explains this.

Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc896548.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not the solution of this problem.

Comment: Hint: if you have to unshelve a shelveset from another user, mention the user domain name in the form "NuGet Build;theOtherUser"

Comment: This was it for me, too tfpt has to be on the path.

Answer (score 6):

I know this has been answered but for me the problem was easily solved by using Visual Studio command prompt instead of the default windows CMD. Most solutions out there just say "Open CMD..." which is probably where the problem lies.

The reason is windows CMD is aware of the power tools commands (e.g. tfpt) but not of the normal VS commands (e.g. tf).