# Could not complete the action error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

I keep getting below message when I open any cshtml/aspx/ascx file in visual studio. I thought it is for any particular solution but it is happening for any solution(website) i open in visual studio. Not able to figure out , why this pop up message is showing.

[image]

I am using visual studio 2013 and I have not updated or changed any settings from last few days. Please help!!!!

Comment: I had same error. Error popped whenever I tried to paste code. It started after I used TFS Power Tools to unshelf a shelfset to a different branch. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303506/unshelve-to-another-branch . I'm not 100% sure if it was caused by the action of installing tfpt, or the unshelf action.

Answer (score 6):

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete the projectName.csproj.user file from the
   project folder
3. Open the solution... message should be gone

Also try updating visual studio

Comment: thanks for your response ...but this works for web applications. I am having this problem in website.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your question then, But the problems lies with <@register in apsx files.

Comment: i am getting this in usercontrols(ascx) also,.. don't know what cause this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling all extensions and see if that works. If it does re-enable one at a time to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ".vb", ".c#" codefiles exist.

If that did not solve the problem, make sure that your class name in the file is the same as defined in line one of your aspx file:

ASPX file:

.VB or .C# File:

```
 Public Class MyTestClassFile
```